# Clearing WinGhci's command prompt (and also its values)

Tags: haskell, winghci

How can I clear WinGhci's (one of Haskell's Windows IDEs) command prompt and all the current "session" values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `:load` with no arguments to clear all modules and bindings. To clear the prompt simply hit `ctrl + s`.

Answer (score 0):

For me Ctrl +L works on windows :)

Comment: It works with ghci command prompt (ghci.exe), not with winghci gui (winghci.exe). Ctrl L is to load modules.